# Clear shared preference having dynamic keys

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a `SharedPreferences` in my app using a dyanmic key generated using a combination of some fixed String and id(unique id for each item).

Get values from shared preference

```
public static int getSharedPref(Context context, String keyName) {
    SharedPreferences betaPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return betaPref.getInt("getShare" + keyName, 0);
}
```

Save value in shared preference

```
public static void saveSharedPref(Context context, int value, String keyName) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences betaPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = betaPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("getShare" + keyName, value);
        editor.apply();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.e("getShare" + keyName, Log.getStackTraceString(e), e);
    }
}
```

So far it works good, but now I also want to delete these shared preference when user logout from the app.
I know we can use

```
preferences.edit().remove("getShare").commit();
```

to remove a particular shared preference, but being a dynamic keys I  don't have a exact name to delete it.

**Query :** Is there any way I can delete all shared preference containing a particular keyword? Or fetch all the keywords used in shared preference and filter them to delete on specific ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing all preferences:

```java
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  = context.getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
```

Removing single preference:

```java
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().remove("key_name").commit();
```

`SharedPreferences` has the method `getAll()` that returns a  `Map<String, ?>` . From the Map you can retrieve easily the keys with `keySet()` and the key/value mappings with `entrySet()`:

```java
Map<String, ?> allEntries = prefA.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
    Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Comment: None of these work for me, as I stated in my question I want to delete only specific shared preference, and those  shared preference have dynamic keys(String + unique id). I won't have keys when deleting them from another screen(logout screen)

Comment: @Nitish have you tried 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22089446/624069

Comment: No I haven't tried, let me give it a shot , Thanks

Comment: You have all keys & value so you can compare with your requirement and clear it.